Verify PDF signature using iText 8
Been using iText to sign PDF files using self signed certificate.
Is there a way to take a PDF as input and verify whether it is signed using my self signed certificate ? (hence verify it was generated by me without any modification).
Since we can't trust the signer name or other signature property i assume (hope) we can verify it against our "secret" certificate even tough it is self signed one.
Thanks in advance for any help.

In Adobe Acrobat, you can add your self-signed certificate as a trusted certificate.
Via iText you can extract the signature, get the signing certificate and compare it to yours, you still have to validate the document.

Starting with iText 8.0.5 new API was introduced for signatures validation. In order to use it, you need to create SignatureValidator instance using ValidatorChainBuilder. Beforehand, you need to provide all the certificates you consider trustworthy, in order for the validation to be successful, by using ValidatorChainBuilder#withTrustedCertificates method. In this case, your self-signed certificate should be provided as trusted. In this case, iText will perform complete signature validation, which can only be successful in case signature was generated with your self-signed certificate as an anchor, and you should be able to see the resulting report.
If the result is VALID, then this pdf was indeed signed using the certificate in question. If it is not, then more detailed investigation might be required. Since signature validation process is quite complicated, other unrelated issues may be reported, which violate ETSI signing standard. So even if a file was indeed signed with the certificate in question, result may still be INDETERMINATE or even INVALID.
However it is possible to modify validation logic the way you want it to be modified, to a certain extent at least. For instance one can completely disable everything related to revocation data validation by simply creating custom RevocationDataValidator, which basically does nothing, and providing this instance in ValidatorChainBuilder#withRevocationDataValidator method. Same is applicable for other validation aspects. See ValidatorChainBuilder and SignatureValidationProperties for more details. Of course one needs to be careful, to not accidentally disable something, without which validation is not performed at all.
